# Converting Date time using respective tz values in another column

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have tried to look up previous answers, if anyone thinks this has been answered before please direct me to link.

I have a dataframe (Tickets) with 4 Date time values - and in another column I have timezone values.

sample dataset as below.

```
TIMEZONE,Creation_Datetime
US/Mountain,2013-07-09 10:08:00 
US/Central,2014-03-24 05:37:13
US/Pacific,2013-01-26 04:30:57
US/Eastern,2013-01-21 02:59:18
US/Eastern,2014-02-24 08:39:17
US/Eastern,2013-02-05 02:30:36
```

I need to convert creation_Datetime in all rows as per the timezone in corresponding row.

```
Tickets$Creation_Datetime= with_tz(
  Tickets$Creation_Datetime,
  as.character(Tickets$TIMEZONE)
)
```

...throws an error "invalid tz value".

It works with a single tz `Tickets$TIMEZONE[1]` value or character value `'US/Mountain'` passed as timezone.

Help with applying 'apply' function to all rows.

Comment: What language or framework is this?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [R - UTC to LOCAL time given Olson timezones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592178/r-utc-to-local-time-given-olson-timezones)