# R - UTC to LOCAL time given Olson timezones

Tags: r, datetime, dst, iso8601

I have time series data from 1974-2013 with a column for datetimeUTC (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm +0000), and a column for the timezones in Olson format (e.g., Canada/Pacific, Canada/Eastern). I can convert the whole UTCdatetime column to a common timezone like this:

```
dataset$datetimeEST <- strptime(
  dataset$datetimeUTC, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z", tz="Canada/Eastern"
)
```

How do I convert `datetimeUTC` to `datetimeLOCAL`, given the corresponding timezone in each row?

Let me back up a bit. I have data from across the country (6 timezones)  formatted in ISO8601 representation for 1974-2013. The timestamps are in local standard time throughout the year (i.e. DST is disregarded even if civilian time in the region observes DST). I need to do datetime calculations which are probably safest to do in UTC time, so that's easy. But, I also need to pull data for specific civil time periods, taking into account DST, and do calculations and plots (e.g.,  all the data for rush hour at locations across all 6 timezones) for that subsetted data.

The datetimeCLOCKTIME that I calculated below appears to be doing what I want for plotting, but gives the wrong answer when doing datetime calculations because it stored the datetime in the timezone of my local machine without having actually converted the time. The solution offered by @thelatemail is what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to get it to work in Windows on the test dataset for 2012 (see below). Also, I was using strptime which converts to POXITlt, and his solution is in POXITct. I'm new to R, so any help would be infinitely appreciated.

Test dataset:

```
    dataset <- data.frame (timestampISO8601 = c("2012-04-25T22:00:00-08:00","2012-04-25T22:15:00-08:00","2012-04-25T22:30:00-08:00","2012-04-25T22:45:00-08:00","2012-04-25T23:00:00-08:00","2012-04-25T23:15:00-08:00","2012-04-25T23:30:00-08:00","2012-04-25T23:45:00-08:00","2012-04-26T00:00:00-08:00","2012-04-26T00:15:00-08:00","2012-04-26T00:30:00-08:00","2012-04-26T00:45:00-08:00","2012-04-26T01:00:00-08:00","2012-04-26T01:15:00-08:00","2012-04-26T01:30:00-08:00","2012-04-26T01:45:00-08:00","2012-04-26T02:00:00-08:00","2012-04-25T22:00:00-03:30","2012-04-25T22:15:00-03:30","2012-04-25T22:30:00-03:30","2012-04-25T22:45:00-03:30","2012-04-25T23:00:00-03:30","2012-04-25T23:15:00-03:30","2012-04-25T23:30:00-03:30","2012-04-25T23:45:00-03:30","2012-04-26T00:00:00-03:30","2012-04-26T00:15:00-03:30","2012-04-26T00:30:00-03:30","2012-04-26T00:45:00-03:30","2012-04-26T01:00:00-03:30","2012-04-26T01:15:00-03:30","2012-04-26T01:30:00-03:30","2012-04-26T01:45:00-03:30","2012-04-26T02:00:00-03:30"), olson = c("Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Pacific","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland","Canada/Newfoundland"), value = c(0,0,1,2,5,11,17,19,20,19,17,11,5,2,1,0,0,-3,-3,-2,-1,2,8,14,16,17,16,14,8,2,-1,-2,-3,-3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Remove the ":" from the UTC offset. (R is expecting the format nnnn for the UTC offset):

```
    dataset$timestampR<- paste(substr(dataset$timestampISO8601,1,22),substr(dataset$timestampISO8601,24,25),sep="")
```

When converting to UTC time, R defaults to -ve for the UTC offset, making -ve offsets in the timestamps positive:

```
    dataset$datetimeUTC <- strptime(dataset$timestampR, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz="UTC")
```

When converting to MACHINE time like this, R reads the input time and converts it to the time in the timezone of the local machine - in my case, this is Canada/Eastern:

```
    dataset$datetimeMACHINE <- strptime(dataset$timestampR, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

When converting to CLOCKTIME time like this, R reads the input time and assigns the time zone of the local machine (currently EDT on my machine) without doing any time conversions:

```
    dataset$datetimeCLOCKTIME <- strptime(dataset$timestampR,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

See the structure of the dataset:

```
    str(dataset)
```

Plotting behaviours are different

```
    library(ggplot2)
    qplot(data=dataset,x=datetimeUTC,y=value)
    qplot(data=dataset,x=datetimeMACHINE,y=value)
    qplot(data=dataset,x=datetimeCLOCKTIME,y=value)
```

Calculation results differ. Incorrect calculation result for datetimeCLOCKTIME:

```
    range (dataset$datetimeUTC)
    range (dataset$datetimeMACHINE)
    range (dataset$datetimeCLOCKTIME)

    dataset$datetimeUTC[34] - dataset$datetimeUTC[1]
    dataset$datetimeMACHINE[34] - dataset$datetimeMACHINE[1]
    dataset$datetimeCLOCKTIME[34] - dataset$datetimeCLOCKTIME[1]
```

Comment: You can't. The timezone applies to the entire date/time vector, not to a specific element. If you back up a few steps and explain the larger problem you're trying to solve, there might be an easier way to solve it.

Comment: FYI - You should consider using canonical time zones, such as `"America/Toronto"` or `"America/Vancouver"`.  The `"Canada/*"` zones are there mostly for backwards compatibility purposes.  [See the list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you need help in determining the correct zone to use.

Comment: Wait a sec, you said `"DST is disregarded even if civilian time in the region observes DST."`  If that's the case then you shouldn't be using the Olson time zones at all.  A zone like `"Canada/Eastern"` is UTC-05:00 in standard time only.  It's UTC-04:00 during DST.  if that's not what you intended, you should probably use fixed offsets instead.

Comment: @Matt Johnson. The data are collected from instruments that record local standard time, with fixed offsets, all year round and are not adjusted for DST. Some, but not all, of those localities observe DST. So, depending on what I want to do, I need to be able to convert everything from local standard time to local time, taking into account DST where applicable. Thanks for the tip about canonical time zones!

Answer (score 4):

You could format back and forth a bit to get a local time representation in a character format. E.g.:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  datetimeUTC=c("2014-01-01 00:00 +0000","2014-01-01 00:00 +0000"),
  olson=c("Canada/Eastern", "Canada/Pacific"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

#             datetimeUTC          olson
#1 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Eastern
#2 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Pacific

dataset$localtime <- with(dataset, 
     mapply(function(dt,ol) format(
              as.POSIXct(dt,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z",tz=ol),
              "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z"), 
              datetimeUTC, olson
            )
     )

#             datetimeUTC          olson              localtime
#1 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Eastern 2013-12-31 19:00 -0500
#2 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Pacific 2013-12-31 16:00 -0800
```

Comment: On my MacBookPro, I get the same result as you when I run it on the Mac side - which is what I want. However, I'm also using a Windows7 virtual machine on Parallels. When I run your R code on the Windows side it gives me the same clocktime, but in Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: On my MacBookPro, I get the same result as you when I run it on the Mac side - which is what I want. However, I'm also using a Windows7 virtual machine on Parallels. When I run your R code on the Windows side it gives me the same clocktime as your result, but in Eastern Standard Time which is where my machine is located.

Comment: @JAQ - I've tested this on both Linux/Win7 and get the same result both times. I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: R2.15.3 64bit, x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64, Parallels/Win7
$ datetimeUTC: chr "2014-01-01 00:00 +0000" "2014-01-01 00:00 +0000"
$ olson: chr "America/Toronto" "America/Vancouver"
$ localtime: chr "2013-12-31 19:00 Eastern Standard Time" "2013-12-31 16:00 Eastern Standard Time"
R3.0.2 64bit, x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, MacBookPro
$ datetimeUTC: chr  "2014-01-01 00:00 +0000" "2014-01-01 00:00 +0000"
$ olson: chr  "America/Toronto" "America/Vancouver"
$ localtime : chr  "2013-12-31 19:00 -0500" "2013-12-31 16:00 -0800"

Comment: I get the same (wrong) result in Windows on a different computer (Lenovo 2014 model ThinkPad) running Windows7 and R3.0.3 64-bit. So, the problem is not with Parallels. The machine time zone on all of the machines is Eastern Daylight Time. This makes me worry about what else is going awry with dates and times on the Windows machines, especially since most of my work is on the Windows side.

Comment: I uninstalled R and RStudio and installed the most recent versions (3.1.0 and 0.98.953, respectively) on both the Mac and Windows sides. The code works fine now in both Mac and Windows, except it's not working anymore in RStudio on the Mac side. The Mac and Windows operating systems were already up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two time zones to convert to and know the difference in time between UTC and those two.  Using @thelatemail's `dataset`

```
transform(dataset, 
localtime=as.POSIXct(datetimeUTC, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z")-
           c(5*3600,8*3600)[as.numeric(factor(olson))])
 #            datetimeUTC          olson           localtime
#1 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Eastern 2013-12-31 19:00:00
#2 2014-01-01 00:00 +0000 Canada/Pacific 2013-12-31 16:00:00
```

Comment: I considered something like this (potentially using a lookup table), but was concerned daylight savings might break it. It will probably work just fine in a lot of cases though.